# YouTube Oauth with passport.js

Tags: javascript, express, oauth, youtube, passport.js

So I'm trying to add YouTube Oauth to my website. I'm using next.js for my front end and express for back end.

back end:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./passport-setup");

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    })
);

app.get(
    "/login/youtube",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"],
        accessType: "offline",
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.status(200);
    }
);

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening on port 4000"));
```

passport-setup.js:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const YoutubeStrategy = require("passport-youtube-v3").Strategy;
require("dotenv").config();

passport.use(
    new YoutubeStrategy(
        {
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/success",
            scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"],
            authorizationParams: {
                access_type: "offline",
            },
            clientID: process.env.YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
        () => {}
    )
);
```

front end:

```
const Login = () => {
    const makeOauthRequest = async () => {
        await fetch("http://localhost:4000/login/youtube");
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <button>Instagram</button>
                <button>Facebook</button>
                <button>Twitter</button>
                <button>Spotify</button>
                <button onClick={makeOauthRequest}>YouTube</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Every tutorial I've watched does this without a front end library such us react instead they use either raw html or ejs. So the routes they create with express are the front end url routes that the user sees in the website so I thought that when they go to a rout they basically make a get request so I tried doing that with the fetch function but when I press the YouTube button        this error pops up `Error: Unknown authentication strategy "google"` so I changed the the method from google to youtube and now this error pops[image]

Thank You!